# How to Configure React Client, .NET Core 3.1 Backend, Single Tenant SSO

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I'm wondering if this is possible?

I have my entire API locked behind an [Authorize] tag.

And my startup class is configured like so:

```
using Application.TestEntities;
using FluentValidation.AspNetCore;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Persistence;

namespace API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt =>
            {
                opt.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });
            services.AddCors(opt =>
            {
                opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
                {
                    policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
                });
            });
            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADBearer(opt => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", opt));

            services.AddMediatR(typeof(List.Handler).Assembly);
            services.AddControllers().AddFluentValidation(cfg => cfg.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Create>());
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

With my appsettings.json set up thusly:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data source = blahblah.db"
  },
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "<MyTenantId>",
    "ClientId": "<MyClientId>"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

On the client side of things, I'm using react-aad-msal inside my index.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css";
import "react-widgets/dist/css/react-widgets.css";
import "./app/layout/styles.css";
import App from "./app/layout/App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import ScrollToTop from "./app/layout/ScrollToTop";
import dateFnsLocalizer from "react-widgets-date-fns";
import { AzureAD } from "react-aad-msal";
import { authProvider } from "./app/common/util/authProvider";

new dateFnsLocalizer();

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  // <React.StrictMode>
  <AzureAD provider={authProvider} forceLogin={true}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <ScrollToTop>
        <App />
      </ScrollToTop>
    </Router>
  </AzureAD>,
  // </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

authProvider.ts:

```
import { MsalAuthProvider, LoginType } from "react-aad-msal";

const config = {
  auth: {
    authority:
      "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<MyTenantId>",
    clientId: "<MyClientId>",
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000",
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "localStorage" as
      | "localStorage"
      | "sessionStorage"
      | undefined,
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
  },
};

export const authenticationParameters = {
  scopes: ["<WhatDoIEvenPutHere?>"],
};

const options = {
  loginType: LoginType.Redirect,
  tokenRefreshUri: window.location.origin,
};

export const authProvider = new MsalAuthProvider(
  config,
  authenticationParameters,
  options
);
```

The goal is to have my API and my React app locked behind Azure AD authentication, so that you would have to be on my tenant to access either of them.
The user will be redirected to the Microsoft login page via the  component in the client. Upon logging in, they will gain access to the React application as well as the API endpoints.

The question is, is this possible? How to the registrations work in Azure? One registration for the client and one for the API? Or one registration that both apps reference? What about scopes? Exposing the API?

**Edit:**

I... think I got it?

One registration in Azure.

Authenticate as SPA with http://localhost:3000 as the redirect URI.
Check both "Access tokens" and "ID tokens" under Implicit Grant.

Expose an API with App ID URI "api://(guid)"
Add scope: name whatever you want - I used "api", so it shows up as "api://(guid)/api"

API Permissions -> Add a permission -> MY APIs -> select the application and check the scope you added previously.

And in your authProvider.ts put in the scope: ["(guid)/(YourScopeName)"], so mine is ["(guid)/api"]

It seems to be working now. In postman I can put in the bearer token that I get back from logging in, and get back data, and when I disable it, I get back a 401. So that's what I'm looking for pretty much.

To anyone reading this please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong or inadvisable.

Comment: According to your description, your thought is right. Have you tried it and what error do you face?

Comment: After my edit, there is no error.

Comment: Since your issue has been resolved by yourself, could you please post your answer?

Comment: I have discovered a new issue. After leaving the application running for long enough for the token to expire, it requires the user to input their credentials through Microsoft again. Of course this is normal, but upon doing so, it seems to try to redirect over and over, failing to authenticate.
It gives the error message: 
"ClientAuthError: invalid key: ... cached token key is not a valid JSON and cannot be parsed"
Clearing the browser cache eliminates the problem.

Comment: could you please tell me the error message

Comment: "ClientAuthError: invalid key: ... cached token key is not a valid JSON and cannot be parsed"

Comment: please refer to https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2492

Comment: Thank you. According to some, this is a bug in msal 1.4.2. I have downgraded to 1.4.1, as was suggested in the thread, and we will see if the problem persists.

I'll also mark my edit as the answer to the original problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my edit in the original post:

One registration in Azure.

Authenticate as SPA with http://localhost:3000 as the redirect URI. Check both "Access tokens" and "ID tokens" under Implicit Grant.

Expose an API with App ID URI "api://(guid)" Add scope: name whatever you want - I used "api", so it shows up as "api://(guid)/api"

API Permissions -> Add a permission -> MY APIs -> select the application and check the scope you added previously.

And in your authProvider.ts put in the scope: ["(guid)/(YourScopeName)"], so mine is ["(guid)/api"]